# Frequency of a value in R

Tags: r, dataset, frequency, software

If there is a data set in R and I want know how many of one value is in it, is there a command for this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values are discrete, you can just use

summary(factor(x))

If you just want to know how often a specific value occurs, then the snippet

sum(x==v)

works quite nicely. Beware of NAs, however (e.g. using `na.rm=T`).

If the value is not discrete, then the notion of "frequency" becomes somewhat ill-defined. The above approach would still work, but I would be very cautious about interpreting the results.

Comment: `table(x)` is often helpful as an alternative